# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\ Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    include("conecta.php");

    $id = 0;
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $pis = $_POST['pis'];
    $dataCadastroPIS = $_POST['dataCadastroPIS'];
    $rg = $_POST['rg'];
    $orgaoEmissor = $_POST['orgaoEmissor'];
    $ufRG = $_POST['ufRG'];
    $dataExpedicao =$_POST['dataExpedicao'];
    $carteiraTrabalho = $_POST['carteiraTrabalho'];
    $numeroSerie = $_POST['numeroSerie'];
    $ufProf = $_POST['ufProf'];
    $emissaoProf = $_POST['emissaoProf'];
    $cnh = $_POST['cnh'];
    $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
    $emissaoCNH = $_POST['emissaoCNH'];
    $validadeCNH = $_POST['validadeCNH'];
    $primeiraCNH = $_POST['primeiraCNH'];
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $zona = $_POST['zona'];
    $secao = $_POST['secao'];
    $reservista = $_POST['reservista'];
    $serie = $_POST['serie'];
    $emissaoReservista = $_POST['emissaoReservista'];
    $tipoReservista = $_POST['tipoReservista'];
    $sus = $_POST['sus'];
    $cidadao = $_POST['cidadao'];
    $logradouro = $_POST['logradouro'];
    $numero = $_POST['numero'];
    $complemento = $_POST['complemento'];
    $bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
    $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
    $cep = $_POST['cep'];
    $uf = $_POST['uf'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
    $raca = $_POST['raca'];
    $cabelo = $_POST['cabelo'];
    $olho = $_POST['olho'];
    $sangue = $_POST['sangue'];
    $altura = $_POST['altura'];
    $peso = $_POST['peso'];
    $calcado = $_POST['calcado'];
    $deficiente = $_POST['deficiente'];
    $tipoDeficiencia = $_POST['tipoDeficiencia'];
    $doencaGrave = $_POST['doencaGrave'];
    $nacionalidade = $_POST['nacionalidade'];
    $dataNascimento = $_POST['dataNascimento'];
    $cidadeNascimento = $_POST['cidadeNascimento'];
    $estadoCivil = $_POST['estadoCivil'];
    $conjuge = $_POST['conjuge'];
    $dataNascimentoConjuge = $_POST['dataNascimentoConjuge'];
    $pai = $_POST['pai'];
    $dataNascimentoPai = $_POST['dataNascimentoPai'];
    $mae = $_POST['mae'];
    $dataNascimentoMae = $_POST['dataNascimentoMae'];
    $filho = $_POST['filho'];
    $dataNascimentoFilho = $_POST['dataNascimentoFilho'];
    $filho2 = $_POST['filho2'];
    $dataNascimentofilho2 = $_POST['dataNascimentoFilho2'];
    $instrucao = $_POST['instrucao'];
    $instituicao = $_POST['instituicao'];
    $especialidade = $_POST['especialidade'];
    $dependente = $_POST['dependente'];
    $dataNascimentoDependente = $_POST['dataNascimentoDependente'];
    $estadoCivilDependente = $_POST['estadoCivilDependente'];
    $tipoDependente = $_POST['tipoDependente'];
    $cpfDependente = $_POST['cpfDependente'];
    $rgDependente = $_POST['rgDependente'];
    $dependente2 = $_POST['dependente2'];
    $dataNascimentoDependente2 = $_POST['dataNascimentoDependente2'];
    $estadoCivilDependente2 = $_POST['estadoCivilDependente2'];
    $tipoDependente2 = $_POST['tipoDependente2'];
    $cpfDependente2 = $_POST['cpfDependente2'];
    $rgDependente2 = $_POST['rgDependente2'];
    $sexoDependente2 = $_POST['sexoDependente2'];
    $dependente3 = $_POST['dependente3'];
    $dataNascimentoDependente3 = $_POST['dataNascimentoDependente3'];
    $estadoCivilDependente3 = $_POST['estadoCivilDependente3'];
    $tipoDependente3 = $_POST['tipoDependente3'];
    $cpfDependente3 = $_POST['cpfDependente3'];
    $rgDependente3 = $_POST['rgDependente3'];
    $sexoDependente3 = $_POST['sexoDependente3'];
    $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
    $matricula2 = $_POST['matricula2'];
    $dataIngresso = $_POST['dataIngresso'];
    $cargo1 = $_POST['cargo1'];
    $dataIngressoCargo1 = $_POST['dataIngressoCargo1'];
    $cargo2 = $_POST['cargo2'];
    $dataIngressoCargo2 = $_POST['dataIngressoCargo2'];
    $secretaria = $_POST['secretaria'];
    $chefia = $_POST['chefia'];
    $local1 = $_POST['local1'];
    $local2 = $_POST['local2'];
    $local3 = $_POST['local3'];
    $obsFinais = $_POST['obsFinais'];

    $sql=$mysqli->prepare("insert into cadastro values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,
        ?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    $sql->bind_param("isssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
                    ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
                    sssssssssssssssssssssssss", $id, $nome,$cpf, $pis, $dataCadastroPIS,$rg, $orgaoEmissor,$ufRG, $dataExpedicao,$carteiraTrabalho,$numeroSerie,$ufProf,$emissaoProf,$cnh,$categoria,$emissaoCNH,$validadeCNH,$primeiraCNH,$titulo,$zona,$secao,$reservista,$serie,$emissaoReservista,$tipoReservista,$sus,$cidadao,$logradouro,$numero,$complemento,$bairro,$cidade,$uf,$telefone,$email,
                    $sexo, $raca,$cabelo,$olho,$sangue,$altura,$peso,$calcado,$deficiente,$tipoDeficiencia,$doencaGrave,$nacionalidade,$dataNascimento, $cidadeNascimento, $estadoCivil,$conjuge,$dataNascimentoConjuge,
                    $pai, $dataNascimentoPai,$mae,$dataNascimentoMae,$filho, $dataNascimentofilho,$filho2,$dataNascimentoFilho2,$instrucao,$instituicao ,   $especialidade,
                    $dependente, $dataNascimentoDependente, $estadoCivilDependente, $tipoDependente, $cpfDependente, $rgDependente, $sexoDependente, $dependente2, $dataNascimentoDependente2,$estadoCivilDependente2, $tipoDependente2, $cpfDependente2, $rgDependente2, $sexoDependente2, $dependente3, $dataNascimentoDependente3, $estadoCivilDependente3, $tipoDependente3, $cpfDependente3, $rgDependente3, $sexoDependente3, 
                    $matricula, $matricula2, $dataIngresso, $cargo1, $dataIngressoCargo1, $cargo2, $dataIngressoCargo2,
                    $secretaria, $chefia, $local1, $local2, $local3, $obsFinais);

    $sql->execute();

    $sql->store_result();

    $result=$sql->affected_rows;

    if($result > 0){
        echo "Dados Inseridos com Sucesso!";
    }else{
        echo "Houve um erro";
    }

?>

alguem sabe resolver esse erro?
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso é **erro de digitação** seu. No meio do seu insert tem diversos `??`, ou seja faltam virgulas entre eles, você está passando **97 parametros**, mas nas interrogações você só passou 91, contando pelas virgulas, logo deu erro na query, acerte as virgulas que faltam de:

```
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,
        ?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Para:

```
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: Não entendi o negativo. A postagem não ficou muito bonita esteticamente , mas é a solução.

Comment: Remanejei o código porém ainda permanece o erro.

Comment: @PatrickBarbosa mesmo erro? Outro erro? O que?